# yield from a list of generators created from an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I've got this recursive generator

```js
var obj = [1,2,3,[4,5,[6,7,8],9],10]

function *flat(x) {
    if (Array.isArray(x))
        for (let y of x)
            yield *flat(y)
    else
        yield 'foo' + x;

}

console.log([...flat(obj)])
```

It works fine, but I don't like the `for` part. Is there a way to write it functionally? I tried

```
if (Array.isArray(x))
   yield *x.map(flat)
```

which didn't work.

Is there a way to write the above function without `for` loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and check the length of the rest array for another calling of the generator

```js
function* flat(a, ...r) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        yield* flat(...a);
    } else {
        yield 'foo' + a;
    }
    if (r.length) {
        yield* flat(...r);
    }
}

var obj = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 9], 10];
console.log([...flat(obj)])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A similar approach but with a `spread` generator for calling the handed over generator with the spreaded values.

```js
function* spread(g, a, ...r) {
    yield* g(a);
    if (r.length) {
        yield* spread(g, ...r);
    }
}

function* flat(a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        yield* spread(flat, ...a);
    } else {
        yield 'foo' + a;
    }
}

var obj = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 9], 10];
console.log([...flat(obj)])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `map` is a good idea, but you need to reduce the resulting array of generator objects to just one generator object:

```js
function *flat(x) {
    if (Array.isArray(x)) 
        yield *x.map(flat).reduce((a, b) => function*() { yield *a; yield *b }());
    else
        yield 'foo' + x;
}

var obj = [1,2,3,[4,5,[6,7,8],9],10];
console.log([...flat(obj)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If we're going to `arr.map(fn).reduce(y* a; y* b)`, can't we re-write this as just a reduce `arr.reduce(y* a; y* fn(b))`?

Comment: @Paul, then `a` will at some point be a primitive value, which is not iterable, and so `yield* a` will raise an exception.

Comment: @PaulS.: this is what Yury did, if you do that you'll have to provide an init value (an empty generator).

Comment: @trincot: nice solution, we can factor out reduce  into a separate function (which is called `chain` in python) and then use `yield *chain(x.map(....)`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to write it functionally, without `for` loops?

No, not really. (Of course you can always opt for recursion instead, but I'll question the usefulness of that approach).

What we're looking for are functional combinators for iterators:

```
function* of(x) { // also known as `pure` or `return`
    yield x;
}
function map(f) { return function* (xs) { // also known as `fmap`
    for (const x of xs)
        yield f(x);
}
function* join(xss) { // also known as `concat` (not `append`!) or `flatten` (but non-recursive!)
    for (const xs of xss)
        for (const x of xs)
            yield x;
}
function chain(f) { return function* (xs) { // also known as `concatMap` or `bind`
    for (const x of xs)
        const ys = f(x);
        for (const y of ys)
            yield y;
}
// or const chain = f => compose(concat, map(f)) :-)
```

Now we can just treat iterators as a **monad**, and be no more concerned about the implementation.

As you can see, I have not used the syntax `yield* xs` above which is (basically) just sugar for

```
for (const x of xs)
    yield x;
```

What is looking weird in your implementation is the disparity between the outer loop and the inner non-loop. In an optimal world, there would be a **`yield**` syntax** that did what `join` does, but there's not. So we can only implement your function nicely with the above helper functions:

```
function* flat(x) {
    if (Array.isArray(x))
        yield* chain(flat)(x);
    else
        yield* of('foo' + x); // foreshadowing
}
```

or just

```
function flat(x) {
    return Array.isArray(x) ? chain(flat)(x) : of('foo' + x);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Asking for "functional" be prepared for a "monadic" answer ;) A question to your code: why `ys`? Is there anything wrong with `for(const y of f(x))` or it's just a style preference?

Comment: @georg That was just about showing through variable names that `f` returns a list without having type signatures, and emphasising that `y` is on a different level than `x`. It looks weird though and is not my style preference :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce array to generator. But this looks worse than for loop to me (though is functional :) )

```js
var obj = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 9], 10]

function* flat(x) {
  if (Array.isArray(x))
    yield * x.reduceRight(
      (f, y) => function*() {
        yield * flat(y);
        yield * f()
      },
      function*() {}
    )()
  else
    yield 'foo' + x;

}

console.log([...flat(obj)])
```

Answer (score -1):

may be something like

```
var obj = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 9], 10];

function* flat(x) {
    if (Array.isArray(x)) {
        yield x.map(v => {
            return [...flat(v)].join();
        });
    } else yield "foo" + x;
}

console.log([...flat(obj)]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't do what I want.