# flatMap instead of for of

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this;

```
let subs = [];
 for ( const item of items ) { // array
        for ( const sub of item ) { // array
            subs.push( sub );
        }
    }
```

and want the same result with this (version 2):

```
 const arr = Object.values(items).map(item => 
         item.map(sub => sub)
    );
```

However, in version 2, I get for each "item" a array of "subs" instead of one array holding all "subs" (like in version 1). I need something like "flatMap". Or how can I do that?

Comment: Is `items` an array? If so, then don't use `Object.values`.

Comment: You might want to write a [`flatMap` generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735702/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, `flatMap` is rather trivial in ES6

```
let flatMap = (a, fn) => [].concat(...a.map(fn));
```

example:

```js
let flatMap = (a, fn) => [].concat(...a.map(fn));

items = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

console.log(flatMap(items, x=>x))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you know, which performs faster (version 1 or 2)? I think, "for..of"..

Comment: No idea, but I doubt there will be a noticeable difference unless you have thousands of items.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using reduce would be

```
items.reduce ((flat, item) => flat.concat (item), [])
```

```js
var items = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
var flat = items.reduce ((flat, item) => flat.concat (item), []);
console.log (flat)
```

A recursive version is almost as simple:

```js
var reducer = (flat, item) => Array.isArray (item)?item.reduce(reducer,flat):flat.concat (item);
var items = [[1,2,3,[7,8,9]],[4,5,6]]

console.log (items.reduce(reducer, []))
```