# Merge array of Sets into single Set

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of Sets, what is the best method to combine these Sets into a single Set?

Say if I had this array:

`const array = [new Set([1, 2, 3]), new Set([4, 5, 6]), new Set([7, 8, 9])]`

How would I manipulate this array in order to produce a single Set with the same output as:

`new Set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`

This array has an arbitrary number of sets of arbitrary size.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `new Set([...array[0], ...array[1], ...array[2]])`?

Comment: I tried using the spread operator `new Set(...array)`, but it only expands the first Set. I tried using the spread operator within array.map, but kept running into issues. `new Set(array.map(set => ...set))` gives me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`

Comment: @D.Wood Spread *syntax* works only within array literals. It's not an operator that produces a value.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is the best:

```
let result = new Set;
for (const set of array)
    for (const element of set)
        result.add(element);
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the constructor, I'd go for an immediately invoked generator function to create an iterator:

```
const result = new Set(function* () {
    for (const set of array)
        yield* set;
}());
```

Of course you can also declare a [reusable functional-minded generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735702/1048572) for this:

```
function* flatten(iterable) {
    for (const inner of iterable)
        for (const element of inner)
            yield element;
}
const result = new Set(flatten(array));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `reduce`

```
new Set( array.reduce( ( a, c ) => a.concat( [...c] ), [] ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var array = [new Set([1, 2, 3]), new Set([4, 5, 6]), new Set([7, 8, 9])];
var output = new Set( array.reduce( ( a, c ) => a.concat( [...c] ), [] ) );
console.log( [...output] );
```

Comment: NOTE: doing [...c] will eliminate duplicate entries in an "c" array,

Comment: @A.T. It will happen anyways since the output is expected to go in a `Set` and it will eliminate all duplicate entries anyways.

Comment: @A.T. No, the duplicates are already eliminated because `c` is a `Set`. Spreading it does not make a difference.

Comment: `[...output]` is actually converting the `Set` into an array. You could iterate over the set `keys()` or `values()` but it's easier to convert it into to array an console output it